# Push commits to different repositories in some folders

Tags: git

I have a specific problem with git.
I have BASE folder. And there are a lot of folders in BASE. 
There's initialized git in each folder and `git remote origin N`. And this `N` is different.
Is it possible to create repository in BASE folder and when I push somethig from children folders, push to BASE repository as well.

```
BASE:
/first
/second
...
/etc
```

It is like there are a lot of small repositories for each child folder and one BASE repository.
Yes, I know that I could remove all small repositories and initialize only BASE repo but small folders should push to gitlab and BASE folder should push to github.

Comment: Looks like you should take a look on git features called `submodule` or `subtree`.

Comment: This may help https://codewinsarguments.co/2016/05/01/git-submodules-vs-git-subtrees/